# Real time graphical browser mmo game, language options?

Tags: php, jquery, flash, browser

i cam across some older topics about this but since there is a lot of new techniques for creating web content i have to ask again.

**My background:**
I have good knowledge of xhtml/css/javascript/php/mysql. I have no trouble making a webshop from scratch including a comprehensive database and a cms to easily add/modify products. I am very comfortable using PHP and mysql to store data. A attempt at a tribal wars clone does not scare me at all. I also made a couple of games with c#/xna but i am still considering myself novice. I dabbled with flash and feel this could probably be used to get the result i want.

**My project:**
A 2D mmo tactical shooter. Players should be able to move across a fairly large maps and get  position updates of other users very quickly. The game will hold a lot of maps and most maps should be able to handle just a couple of players. Hub maps and maps of interest however should be able to handle at least 100 players without lag.

It would be awesome if combat could be resolved real time on the map but i already thought of other ways to resolve this like opening an instance map where players could enter to join combat. I'm also considering a more tactical turn based approach on combat but it depends on the pro's and con's of real time combat.

**To sum it up:**
I am sure i can manage everything except for the graphical implementation. Mysql should not have much trouble querying the local player positions in a couple of milliseconds.

I cam across a game named Deeppolis that pretty much resembles graphically what i want. I'm still considering making this as a downloadable client but i am very interested what my options are if i'm going to do this browser based as browser based games tend to get more people attracted.

Thanks for reading this wall of text :D.

Comment: Ok, what's the question?

Comment: Flash is your best option at this point in time imo. You can also wrap it using AIR to make it a downloadable client with little or no modifications.

Comment: Not totally sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems like it might be an interesting choice: http://meteor.com/  It uses mongoDB as a datastore, so it should have pretty fast read/writes to all participants.

Comment: AIR is somekind of api/extension? I will look into that. I will also look into meteor, but the answere below sugests i use sockets which sounds smart :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would not want to "query mysql" to get player positions if this is real time. You will want to create a socket server that all clients connect to. the socket server would keep a subscriber list of all connected clients in memory. this way when one client sends a message to the socket server, the socket server can immediately push needed data to whichever clients need it. you would also want to keep a model of the game state in memory in your socket server to prevent cheating etc. you would only use a database for long term storage, everything else should be in memory. also keep in mind shared servers will likely not allow you access to sockets to create a socket server, so you will need a private server.

client side: javascript & [socket.io](http://socket.io/) (socket client)

server side: javascript & [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) (socket server)

Comment: Ok thank you, i will look into this. Does javascript implement well between flash?

Comment: @MennoGouw why would you use both? flash does not need javascript to make something like this, and javascript would only need socket.io to make something like this.

Comment: Well you suggest i use javascript sockets. But javascript isn't going to be enough for the visuals i want (i think). I really need something like flash to make it look attractive. So thats why i need to use both.

Comment: @MennoGouw first, Flash can make a socket connection on its own without needing javascript. second, with html5 and browsers like chrome, i would be curious to know what you think you can do in Flash visually that you cannot do using javascript? Plus javascript can be turned into iPhone and Android native apps using PhoneGap. The only advantage of Flash would be backwards compatability with older browsers.